# EditorFor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-editor-templates, editorfor

for design issue, I need to wrap a lot of input text in a specific template. I hoped to use the editorfor template and I wrote that:

**View**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, "bootstrap_FormInputControls")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, "bootstrap_FormInputControls")
```

**EditorTemplates**

```
@model MyModel
<div class="controls">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Tag, new { placeholder = "Email" })
</div>
```

That of course is not general .. my wish is to use the value that is specified in the EditorFor (Email, Username, ...). Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Editor Templates are based on the type of the input.. Do UserName, Email, etc. all have the same type? Is that type "MyModel"? 

Either way you will want to use the TextBox() rather than TextBoxFor in the template and use the ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix to get the name of the field to pass in.

Comment: No, I have different type .. probably is better if I write a custom HtmlHelper

Comment: Yes, either an HTML Helper or simply a Partial View would do the trick.